# multicombinations with further requirements

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find the number of ways to distribute $n$ balls into $k$ boxes. The boxes  are distinguishable. The balls are not. $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ is the number of all possible distributions. I am working on a problem with following further requirements (one at a time):

i) If $k=3$, what is the number of distribution such that at least one box has at most $m$ balls?

ii) If $k=5$, what is the number of distributions such that at least two boxes are empty?

iii) If $k=5$, what is the number of distribution such that at least two boxes have at most $m$ balls?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first one is fairly straightforward: the ‘bad’ distributions are the ones in which each box has at least $m+1$ balls, and you probably know how to count those. Then subtract them from the total.

Comment: Thanks, that is true. When looking around I saw a post with the at least $m+1$ balls problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKETCH: For the second one, you could count the distributions in which no box is empty and the distributions in which exactly one box is empty, and subtract the total from the number of unrestricted distributions. The distributions in which no box is empty are of course those in which each box contains at least one ball; that’s a problem with a known solution. For the rest, count the distributions in which Box $1$ is empty and the others are not; that’s the same problem with one box fewer. Then adjust that to account for the fact that any one of the boxes could be empty.

You can adapt the same idea for the third problem. Count the distributions in which no box has at most $m$ balls (i.e., in which every box has at least $m+1$ balls), then count those in which exactly one box has at most $m$ balls.

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely correct. Your approach lead me to a correct (few numerical checks) answer. The approach can be used, with minor modifications, to answer iii) as well.

Comment: @Jan: You're welcome.